# Howto draw a half border in xml android

Tags: android, xml, border

I want to draw a border like this , 
[Bordered Edittext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubwqF.png)

my code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp">
        <!--// add android:right="5dp" and android:left="5dp" for border on left and right-->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/bill_background" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I managed to do something like this: [My Edittext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvH00.png)

I cant seem to adjust the height of the left and right sided borders.

Comment: What you want to do, is not clear can you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: i want a border that looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubwqF.png but i am only able to make something like this http://imgur.com/nSanLqJ
please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code! this will surely help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#00f" />

            <padding android:bottom="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />

            <padding
                android:left="2dp"
                android:right="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: thanks a lot brother , it really helped out a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Toufiq Akbar.
You should use Vector drawable.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="400.0"
    android:viewportWidth="580.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M41.5,318L534.7,318"
        android:strokeColor="#000"
        android:strokeWidth="1.5" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M535.5,210L535.5,319"
        android:strokeColor="#000"
        android:strokeWidth="1.5" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M42.5,209L42.5,318"
        android:strokeColor="#000"
        android:strokeWidth="1.5" />
</vector>
```

I think It is useful to you... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp">
        <!--// add android:right="5dp" and android:left="5dp" for border on left and right-->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="@color/red" />
            <size android:height="50dp" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="10dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <!--// add android:right="5dp" and android:left="5dp" for border on left and right-->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <padding android:bottom="5dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

Use this.