# Create shorter border than its view by using android drawable layer ist

Tags: android, border, android-drawable

I have been searching on how to draw a border line that has shorter length that it container for few days. Basically I want to achieve below results i.e borders that do not have reach its edge. 
[image]

So far this is what I have achieved:
[image]

I was thinking it is impossible and not supported by android drawable, until I found this post [Howto draw a half border in xml android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41219580/howto-draw-a-half-border-in-xml-android) . It illustrates how to draw a C shape border by using android drawable layer list. I tried to modify and fit into my purpose, but I cannot achieve the expected result

I am not good in android drawable and please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: Did you try adding padding to item in minus value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<View
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  android:background="#9c9c9c"
  android:layout_width="2dp"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/view_sise"/>
```

[image]

It will look like this.

Answer (score 1):

First you take outer rectangle box and align to a layout, and then take inner lines separately and add them using inner layouts.

Inner layout align:

```
<View
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  android:background="#9c9c9c"
  android:layout_width="2dp"
  android:layout_height="desired"/>
```